# Issue with clickable links when running jquery

Tags: jquery

We've set up some fun jquery additions in two places:
http://artsygeek.com.s141242.gridserver.com/565  (the 404 error page)
http://artsygeek.com.s141242.gridserver.com/services/magic

The top menu is still functioning normally, but the links in the content and the footer are not showing up as clickable!

The last sentence on the magic page is a link, and the ul on the 404 error page should all be clickable links.

We're totally baffled.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Jennifer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a div that is over your content. 
Add this to your code, in the `style.css` file at line 85:

```
#lefthalf {
   z-index: -1;
}
```

It will work fine after this.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is that `<div id="lefthalf"></div>` is covering the links.  If you alter the CSS styling of that element (z-index, size, etc.) so that it is no longer overlapping on top of the other items, then all the links will be clickable again.  Essentially, the DIV is sitting top of them, so they only *appear* to be unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

Your footer is overlapping by `lefthalf div`.

You can add this to `#colophon` to fix the problem

```
#colophon {
      position:relative;
      z-index:199;

}
```